# Is there any way to request dark version of website in android using webView?

Tags: android, webview

I am building dark mode for my browser app and I would love to provide users the exact dark mode, which means not just the UI of browser would be black but also the website users visit turns into black. There are some chrome extensions that are capable of doing that but I was wondering if there is any method in Android's WebView as well or not.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dark mode with a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720952/using-dark-mode-with-a-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code it may work

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    String rawHTMLData = "<HTML>"+ 
     "<head>"+"<style  type=\"text/css\">"+
     "body,h1{color: #000000;"+
     "background-color: #ffffff;}"+
     "</style></head>"+
     "<body><h1>Hello Android </h1></body>"+  
 "</HTML>";
    webview1.loadData(rawHTMLData, "text/html; charset=UTF-8",null);
```

Comment: Hey, I need to load a web page from internet. Like I want to get the dark mode of Youtube instead of a white one.

Comment: you can set background to webview like any color which u want and may be its work