# Using dark mode with a webview

Tags: android, css, android-webview, android-dark-theme

I can't seem to be able to get android web view to use dark theme or use

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
```

I am using AndroidX with DayNight theme

Does anyone has a solution that is backward compatible before api 29?

Answer (score 7):

Add to your app's build.grade:

```
implementation "androidx.webkit:webkit:1.2.0"
```

You can check the latest version to use here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/webkit

If you have a class that extends WebView, then add this in your extending class'  constructor:

```
  public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);

       ...
            
      if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
          WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(getSettings(), WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON);
      }

      ...
  }
```

If you have an activity that that instantiates a webview, add this to the activity's onCreate method:

```
    myWebView = getViewById(R.id.web_content);
    if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
        WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(myWebView.getSettings(),
                                       WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON);
    }
```

Of course, you might want to decide which force strategy you want:

```
WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON
WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_OFF
WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_AUTO
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I used webkit:1.4.0 (Android API 29) :(

Answer (score 0):

For devices running below Android 10, you could add the androidx.webkit dependency and set your webview settings as it follows:

```
if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(myWebView.settings, WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON)
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this code? This is a very incomplete answer. Also, you may want to give more detail about the webkit dependency, such as a sample of how to inject it into the gradle file.